# Calculating the mean for each cell for multiple SpatRasters consisting of many layers?

Tags: raster, r, terra

I have 3 SpatRasters (3 years) consisting of 19 layers (climatic variables). I want to calculate the mean of each variable over the 3 years period.

I tried the following piece of code but the result is a raster with a single layer.

````
vars2006 <- rast("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\vasr2006.tif")
vars2007 <- rast("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\vars2007.tif")

stack <- c(vars2005, vars2006, vars2007)

mean_stack <- app(stack, mean)```


This is what the original rasters look like:
> vars2005
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4680, 6240, 19  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -12.00014, 39.99986, 34.99986, 73.99986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : vars2005.tif 
names       : chels~eur_1, chels~eur_2, chels~eur_3, chels~eur_4, chels~eur_5, chels~eur_6, ... 
min values  :   -16.49167,  -14.033334, -579.364990,    212.0298,      -10.95,      -24.35, ... 
max values  :    20.54167,   -1.266666,   -9.460548,   1123.1277,       27.25,       16.25, ... 


And the resulting raster:
> mean_s
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4680, 6240, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -12.00014, 39.99986, 34.99986, 73.99986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : spat_AeqZ1iVPinJ6LEI_1268.tif 
name        :       mean 
min value   :   1290.218 
max value   : 129383.492
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `tapp` which applies a function to layers of a raster stack based on an index. If your layer names are the same across the source rasters you can use those.

Tip: Always make a tiny example when doing data manipulation, for speed of testing, for reproducibility (adding this code to your SO Q is a good thing) and for verification.

```
one = rast(matrix(1, 3,4)) # a 3x4 raster of value=1
s1 = rast(list(a=one+1, b=one+2, c=one+3)) # some other rasters
s2 = rast(list(a=one+1, b=one+2, c=one+3))
s3 = rast(list(a=one+1, b=one+2, c=one+3))
s4 = rast(list(a=one+1, b=one+2, c=one+3))
```

Each of those is a stack of three rasters which is going to act like each of your yearly raster stacks:

```
> s1                                      
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 3, 4, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 4, 0, 3  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
sources     : memory  
              memory  
              memory  
names       : a, b, c 
min values  : 2, 3, 4 
max values  : 2, 3, 4
```

Stack them all up:

```
stack = rast(list(s1, s2, s3,s4))
```

and get

```
> stack
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 3, 4, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 4, 0, 3  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
sources     : memory  
              memory  
              memory  
              ... and 9 more source(s)
names       : a, b, c, a, b, c, ... 
min values  : 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, ... 
max values  : 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, ...
```

Now I think this what your `stack` looks like - you've only shown the individual parts but I can't be sure. What you want to do now, if I understand, is to get the mean of all the "a" layers, the "b" layers etc.

```
> meanabc = tapp(stack, names(stack), mean)
> meanabc                                 
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 3, 4, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 4, 0, 3  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source      : memory 
names       : a, b, c 
min values  : 2, 3, 4 
max values  : 2, 3, 4
```

And that is now three layers, the first is all 2 as the mean of the "a" layers, the second all 3, the third all 4.

If your names don't match up then you can either set the names to be common across your yearly raster stacks, or create a vector to pass to the `tapp` function that identifies the groupings. For example, the above is equivalent to:

```
> ind = rep(1:3,4) # four lots of "years" with 3 "months" in each
> tapp(stack, ind, mean) # monthly mean over years
```